# Need Background task recommendations for updating firestore data

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-workmanager, background-thread

I'm looking to update the data in Firestore by using some kind of background task. Currently, I'm using a `ListenableWorker`, since Firestore operations are asynchronous and listenable worker supports asynchronous work with `SettableFuture`. But Listenable worker runs the `startWork()` method in the main thread and the periodic work requests are then run in the background if I'm not wrong. I want to run the whole thing (updating data in Firestore) in the background even when the app is not opened throughout the day, but the process should be run periodically throughout the day.